# Filter json data in node js

Tags: json, node.js

I am receiving following data in the form of json

```
 [{
     "Id": 1,
     "sku": "abc",
     "name": "Abbey Black Round Glass and Chrome 3 Tier Stand",
     "qty": 14
   },
   {
     "Id": 3,
     "sku": "abc",
     "name": "Ammy Black Glass and Chrome 5 Tier Corner Stand",
     "qty": 0
   },
   {
     "Id": 4,
     "sku": "abc",
     "name": "Barcelona Adjustable Gas Lift Black Bar Stool (Set of 2)",
     "qty": 0
   }
 ]
```

I have to filter data so that it shows only following key-value pair

```
sku
qty
```

Expected result will be

```
[{
    "sku": "abc",
    "qty": 14
  },
  {

    "sku": "abc",
    "qty": 0
  },
  {

    "sku": "abc",
    "qty": 23
  }
]
```

Any solution to filter data in such a format?. I can filter data based on specific values but I want json data containing only two pairs (sku,qty)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.map()` with array destructuring to make your code simple and short:

```js
var data = [
  {
      "Id": 1,
      "sku": "abc",
      "name": "Abbey Black Round Glass and Chrome 3 Tier Stand",
      "qty": 14
  },
  {
      "Id": 3,
      "sku": "abc",
      "name": "Ammy Black Glass and Chrome 5 Tier Corner Stand",
      "qty": 0
  },
  {
      "Id": 4,
      "sku": "abc",
      "name": "Barcelona Adjustable Gas Lift Black Bar Stool (Set of 2)",
      "qty": 23
   }
];
var res = data.map(({sku, qty}) => ({sku, qty}));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: @mohammadobaid glad to help

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with map like this:

```
var array=[
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "sku": "abc",
        "name": "Abbey Black Round Glass and Chrome 3 Tier Stand",
        "qty": 14
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "sku": "abc",
        "name": "Ammy Black Glass and Chrome 5 Tier Corner Stand",
        "qty": 0
    }];

array.map(function(item) { 
    delete item.Id; 
delete item.name; 
    return item; 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help , however above answer works seamlessly for me